# AJAX request doesnt change text in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently performing a task which involves getting the information from a file using php and returning it using AJAX. The data is getting sent as I tested this using an alert, however for some reason the line:

```
param.html(str);
```

won't change the text in the div...

Here is my function:

```
function updateChat(param) {
    var dataString = 'update=true';
    var str = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/chat.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            str = data;
        }
    });
    param.html(str);
}
```

Here is how I call my method:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    updateChat('#chatbox');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are performing an async request `str` will not be set until the `ajax` request is complete and success handler is invoked. Move `param.html(str)` inside the ajax success handler then it will update the text in the div.

```
function updateChat(param) {
    var dataString = 'update=true';
    var str = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/chat.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
           param.html(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Change this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    updateChat('#chatbox'); //<----
}, 1000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function() {
    updateChat($('#chatbox'));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This however is still not having my text appear in the div

Comment: Can you check what is `data` in the success handler?

Comment: if `param` is a jQuery object and visible on the page then passing a valid string to `html` should work fine.

Comment: @rshah Make sure you're specifying the parameter correctly. e.g. you should be doing `updateChat($("#myDiv"))`, not `updateChat("#myDiv")`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli the method call was the problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because javascript uses async call in Ajax. In your case, the line that assigns param.html(str) is executed before str gets changed as a result of the delay in server call.

```
function updateChat(param) {
    var dataString = 'update=true';
    var str = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/chat.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            str = data; ---> then it's assigned
        }
    });
    param.html(str);  ---> this is executed first
}
```

Move the param.html assignment inside the success function of the Ajax call.